# Angular Material Table: Generic Table Sorting

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a generic reusable datatable component with pagination/sorting/filtering that leverages Material table but removes much of the boilerplate involved in using that throughout the entire application.

The goals of this table are to provide the following:

- mat-table usage with mat-paginator/mat-sort/etc. without a bunch of boilerplate in each template and component that uses it

  - takes an observable data source and handles subscribing and data management
  - allows for data-aware content projection (like *matCellDef)
  - possible to migrate away from mat-table and use different datatable provider in the future without touching anything outside of the generic datatable component (so no mat* directives or components anywhere outside of the generic datatable component itself)

I have already developed this, and it's working great for the most part, but I am having a strange issue specifically with sorting.  Everything loads correctly, and sorting works perfectly -- on the first column.  I can sort as many times as I want and it will work fine on the first column.  As soon as I sort on any other column, I get "ERROR Error: Duplicate column definition name provided:..."  and after that occurs, sort actions on any column (including the first) will just throw that error and do nothing.  Other table interactions (pagination, filtering) will also cease to work in this case.

It makes no difference about which column is in which order or other attributes, whether it has a template defined or not, etc.

Below is an example of using the component and all relevant code.
Thanks for your help in advance!

**Sample file using my datatable component**

```
<app-datatable [dataSource]="testData">
 <app-datatable-column name="name">
  <ng-container *datatableCell="let data">
    <a href="somewhere/{{data.id}}">{{data.name}}</a>
  </ng-container>
 </app-datatable-column>
 <app-datatable-column name="age" label="Years on Earth"></app-datatable-column>
```

**datatable.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  template: `
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="filterable">
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>  
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="loading"></mat-progress-bar>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" *ngIf="pagination"></mat-paginator>`,
})
export class DatatableComponent<T> implements AfterContentInit {
  /** The list of columns which should appear - this will default to all defined columns if not set */
  @Input() columns: string[];
  /** The datasource from which the table should populate */
  @Input() dataSource: Observable<DatatableDataSource<T>>;
  /** Toggles for pagination, sorting, and filtering */
  @Input() pagination: boolean = true;
  @Input() sortable: boolean = true;
  @Input() filterable: boolean = true;
  /** Page size options provided */
  @Input() pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 25, 50, 100];
  /** Default sort options */
  @Input() defaultSortColumn: string;
  @Input() defaultSortDirection: 'asc' | 'desc' = 'asc';

  /** Column definitions added via the DatatableColumn component */
  @ContentChildren(DatatableColumnComponent) datatableColumns: QueryList<DatatableColumnComponent<T>>;

  /** References to the table and row definitions in this template */
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<T>;
  @ViewChild(MatHeaderRowDef) headerRows: MatHeaderRowDef;
  @ViewChildren(MatRowDef) rows: QueryList<MatRowDef<T>>;

  /** Paginator */
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  /** Sorter */
  public sort: MatSort = new MatSort();
  /** The data resultant from the provided dataSource - this is fed directly into the table for display */
  public data: MatTableDataSource<T>;
  /** Whether the data is loading from the source or not */
  public loading: boolean = true;

  /**
   * Apply filter to current data source
   * @param filterValue The value to filter against
   * @return void
   */
  public applyFilter(filterValue: string): void {
    if (this.filterable) {
      this.data.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

      if (this.data.paginator) {
        this.data.paginator.firstPage();
      }
    }
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // define columns if not already set
    this.columns = this.columns || this.datatableColumns.map(column => column.name);

    // set data result and status from source
    this.dataSource.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe((data: DatatableDataSource<T>) => {
      this.loading = data.loading;
      this.data = new MatTableDataSource<T>(data.data);
      this.data.sort = this.sort;
      this.data.paginator = (this.pagination) ? this.paginator : null;

      // if there is sorting, default sort must also be set for table interactions to work
       if (this.sortable) {
        // get a sub-set of columns which are defined as sortable
        const sortableColumns = this.datatableColumns
          .filter(column => (column.sortable && this.columns.includes(column.name)))
          .map(column => column.name);

        // only implement sorting if there are sortable columns
        if (sortableColumns.length > 0) {
          this.data.sort = this.sort;
          this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>{
            id: (this.defaultSortColumn && sortableColumns.includes(this.defaultSortColumn)) ? this.defaultSortColumn : sortableColumns[0],
            start: this.defaultSortDirection
          });
        }
      }
    });

    // register datatable-columns to the table
    this.datatableColumns.forEach(datatableColumn => {
      this.table.addColumnDef(datatableColumn.columnDef);
      // register sort header for each sortable column
      if (datatableColumn.sortable) {
        this.sort.register(<MatSortable>{
          id: datatableColumn.name,
          start: 'asc'
        });

        datatableColumn.sortUpdate.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe((column: string) => {
          this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>{
            id: column,
            start: 'asc'
          });
        });
      }
    });

    // send updated sort direction information back to column for display update when sorting event occurs
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(event => {
      this.datatableColumns.find(column => column.name = event.active).sortDirection = event.direction;
    });
  }
}
```

**datatable-column.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable-column',
  template: `
    <ng-container matColumnDef>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef
        (click)="sort()"
        [class.datatable-header-sort]="sortable"
        [class.datatable-header-sort-asc]="sortable && sortDirection === 'asc'"
        [class.datatable-header-sort-desc]="sortable && sortDirection === 'desc'">
        {{getTitle()}}
        <mat-icon *ngIf="sortable">arrow_right_alt</mat-icon>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
        <ng-container *ngIf="!template">{{getData(data)}}</ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {$implicit: data}"></ng-container>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./datatable-column.component.scss']
})
export class DatatableColumnComponent<T> implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  /** The current direction of the sorting of the column */
  public sortDirection: SortDirection = '';

  /** Column name that should be used to reference this column. */
  @Input()
  get name(): string { return this._name; }
  set name(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
    this.columnDef.name = name;
  }
  _name: string;

  /**
   * Text label that should be used for the column header. If this property is not
   * set, the header text will default to the column name.
   */
  @Input() label: string;

  /**
   * Accessor function to retrieve the data should be provided to the cell. If this
   * property is not set, the data cells will assume that the column name is the same
   * as the data property the cells should display.
   */
  @Input() dataAccessor: ((data: T, name: string) => string);

  /** Alignment of the cell values. */
  @Input() align: 'before' | 'after' = 'before';

  /** Whether the column is sortable */
  @Input() sortable: boolean = true;

  /** Event to emit when sorting is updated */
  @Output() sortUpdate = new EventEmitter<string>();

  /** Reference to column definitions and sort headers */
  @ViewChild(MatColumnDef) columnDef: MatColumnDef;
  @ViewChild(MatSortHeader) sortHeader: MatSortHeader;

  @ContentChild(DatatableCellDirective, {read: TemplateRef}) template;

  constructor(@Optional() public table: MatTable<any>) { }

  /**
   * Gives a formatted version of the name if label is not present
   * @return The formatted label
   */
  public getTitle(): string {
    return this.label || startCase(this.name);
  }

  public getData(data: T): any {
    return this.dataAccessor ? this.dataAccessor(data, this.name) : (data as any)[this.name];
  }

  /**
   * Triggers a sort action on this column by emitting a sort update action to the parent datatable
   */
  public sort(): void {
    this.sortUpdate.emit(this.name);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.table) {
      this.table.addColumnDef(this.columnDef);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.table) {
      this.table.removeColumnDef(this.columnDef);
    }
  }
}
```

**datatable-cell.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[datatableCell]'
})
export class DatatableCellDirective { 
    constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>){}
}
```

Comment: your stackblitz is broken

Comment: Yeah, some strange error where ViewChild wasn't reading my column reference correctly.  I could not reproduce this behavior in a couple different environments running with ng serve/build with/without --prod.  I have replaced the broken StackBlitz link with all the relevant code.